# split (chop?) a binary file in arbitrary number of segments of different predetermined sizes in one single read using bash

Tags: bash, split, binary

Sometimes binary files have formats that are agreed 'beforehands' and have segments of binary data that have independent meaning. For example, a binary file can have a structure

```
{4 bytes of ID}{20 bytes of data}{4 bytes of checksum}
```

I want to split / chop (not sure what word is best) such a binary file in bash, doing one single read, with arbitrary number / sizes of segments. Any idea how to do that?

**Note 1**: I know about other methods that allow to do this in more than 1 read, for example using dd once for each segment:

```
dd if="${INPUT_FILE}" of="${OUTPUT_CRRT_SEGMENT}" skip="${START_SEGMENT}" count="${NBYTES_SEGMENT}" iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes status=none
```

but in this case if I am right, there is no way around performing several reads.

**Note 2**: if this does not exist yet, I am considering writing a small bash function written in C for doing that for me. Do you think this is reasonable?

**Edit 1**: so basically I want a command that can do something in this kind:

`chop --segments=4,20,4 "${FILE_IN}" segment-??`

and that would provide me with `segment-01` containing the first 4 bytes, `segment-02` containing the next 20, `segment-03` containing the next 4 etc etc.

Comment: Ok, so you are in the same 'position' as me then. Would be actually surprised if there is not tool to do this as this sounds like a quite reasonable / common use to me. Maybe a possibility would be to see if this can / should be added to split.

Comment: I can't really think of a real-world use case for such a tool; and most (if not all) standard command-line utilities accept text-files as input rather than binary.

Comment: Maybe I have a strange use, but 'that is my right' ^^ . I agree that it is not 100% clear if this means that the use case is too low level for bash and maybe the whole algo should be written in another language but meh, I looked for it and got no answer, so cannot hurt to 'create some information' on this by opening an issue.

Comment: What's the objection to multiple reads... the OS will cache the reading for you.

Answer (score 1):

If `Perl` is your option, how about:

```
perl -e '
        $arg1 = shift;
        $file = shift;
        $prefix = shift;

        if ($arg1 =~ /--segments=(.+)/) {
                @segs=split(/,/, $1);
        }
        open(FH, $file) or die "$file";
        for $n (@segs) {
                $outfile = sprintf("%s-%02d", $prefix, ++$i);
                open(W, "> $outfile");
                read(FH, $x, $n);
                print W $x;
        }
' -- --segments=4,20,4 "$FILE_IN" segment
```

Then three files segment-01, segment-02 and segment-03 are created which contain the segments of binary data of "$FILE_IN"

Comment: Ok, that's a nice one. So basically defining a very simple parsing perl function and calling it directly from bash, right? :)

Comment: Year, the logic will be mostly same as writing in C. We can just save typing and compiling if we write in Perl.

Comment: Yes, which is great because easier installation and portability, right? :)